# Appropriate word for "intermediate approach"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In a paper, I need to mention something meaning "intermediate approaches" and looking for a suitable word or phrase for that.

For example:

Approach 1 is ...

Approach 2 is ... (Approaches 1 and 2 are the two opposite extremes of the possible approaches)

We have studied many intermediate approaches [between approach 1 and approach 2] and the results are shown in Fig. 1.

Comment: Actually, I think your choice is quite possibly the best. Intermediate implies *somewhere* between two points. There can be many intermediate steps/reactions/approaches. The others seem more limiting towards the middle (median/midway, etc.) or too informal (in between).

Comment: Perhaps *hybrid approaches* -- but without knowing the context, there's a limit to how well one can guess what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

How about nominal *intermediate*?

> We have studied many *intermediates* [between approach 1 and approach 2] and the results are shown in Fig. 1.

[intermediate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intermediate): something intermediate

Answer (score 0):

"Intermediate Approach" is probably the most effective term/phrase for the situation.
If you need variety try

- Dual Approach
- Diverse Approach
- Varied Approach

Answer (score 0):

You could try a **moderate** approach, which may be a **compromise** between the extreme approaches.