# What do you call a person who does not go to both the extremes of the argument but remains in the middle ground?

Tags: vocabulary

The kind of person who does not believe in the extreme sides and always weighs the pros and cons and comes to the conclusion that everything should be in moderation

Comment: ....a moderate.

Comment: Essentially, answered at [Appropriate word for "intermediate approach"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172853/appropriate-word-for-intermediate-approach) (there is also at least one other question asking for a related noun).

Comment: Do you want the word to be complimentary, equivocal or disparaging?!

Comment: I think the correct term is "very rare".

Comment: I would describe that type of person as pragmatic, unless this person chooses the middle ground for its own sake.

Comment: A ***centrist***

Comment: The person *always* wants a "middle ground" and *never* comes down on one side or the other of *any* issue? **Wishy-washy**, or **lacking conviction**, or maybe, if you're trying to be complimentary, **Switzerland**.

Answer (score 1):

You could call that person someone who is:

***[Sitting on the fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitting_on_the_fence)***

> "Sitting on the fence" is a common idiom used in English to describe
>   one's neutrality or hesitance to choose between two sides in an
>   argument or a competition, or inability to decide due to lack of
>   courage

--Wiktionary

Collins describes [the term](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-sit-on-the-fence) as follows:

> If you sit on the fence, you avoid supporting a particular side in a
>   discussion or argument.
>
> They are sitting on the fence and refusing to commit themselves.
>
> He's not afraid of making decisions and is a man who never sits on the
>   fence.

Comment: And the noun-phrase for that person is hence **[fence sitter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fence_sitter)**.

Comment: @AndyT Yes, a fence sitter is someone who is six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: This doesn’t sound quite like what Amalpriya is looking for to me. Being on the fence is, at least to me, inherently about hesitation or uncertainty: it’s about not daring or not having the confidence to choose one side over another. Essentially, it makes you **undecided**. The kind of person we’re looking for here is someone who has weighed the available options and **is decided**, but on a middle ground that rejects both extreme options.

Answer (score 0):

> **middle-of-the-road** adjective
>
> used to describe a person, organization, opinion, or type of entertainment that is not extreme and is acceptable to or liked by most people:
>
> *middle-of-the-road pop music.
>
> They adopted a sensible, middle-of-the-road policy on defence spending.*
>
> [http://dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/middle-of-the-road)

Answer (score 0):

**sees the world in many shades of grey**

Those people will by instinct categorize things neither white or black, right or wrong, but look for the complexity of a moral situation, political situation etc.

Unfortunately I can not find a good dictionary definition of this phrase.

You can google many uses of the idiom/term

Here is the headline and first sentence in a [The Atlantic magazine article](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2011/04/why-do-women-see-the-world-in-shades-of-gray/237880/):

> **Why Do Women See the World in Shades of Gray?**
>
> *A study finds that the sexes interpret the world differently, with men more likely to judge it in black-and-white terms*